# Change a branch's upstream with Magit

Tags: magit, git

When you push a branch with Magit (with `P P`) and the branch has no
upstream, Magit asks you the name of the branch you want to push to.
That's great.

Once you set the upstream for a branch, however, Magit no longer asks
you where you want to push it. This is usually convenient (you don't
want to be asked every time), but it makes it difficult to push a
branch to a different remote branch.

**Is there a way to have Magit ask me again about the destination
  branch, even if the current branch already has an upstream?**

---

### Use-case

It's quite common that I have a branch like this:

```
Local:    issue-30 ~/Git-Projects/repo/
Remote:   issue-30 @ origin (git@github.com:.../repo.git)
Head:     ebe4054 Some commit message
```

and I want to change both Local and Remote branches to `issue-30-and-34`. If I just rename the Local branch, I'm left with this:

```
Local:    issue-30-and-34 ~/Git-Projects/repo/
Remote:   issue-30 @ origin (git@github.com:.../repo.git)
Head:     ebe4054 Some commit message
```

Even if I delete `origin/issue-30`, doing `P P` on `issue-30-and-34`
will simply recreate the `origin/issue-30`.

What I end up doing is the following, but it feels rather roundabout for something that can be done in a single `git` command:

1. Create a new branch called `issue-30-and-34`
   (instead of renaming the old one),
2. delete both Local and Remote versions of `issue-30`,
3. push `issue-30-and-34` (since it has no upstream yet, Magit will ask me where to push).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Starting with `v2.1` you can change the upstream of the current branch to a remote or local branch using <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>`[REMOTE/]BRANCH`<kbd>RET</kbd>. Starting with `v2.4`, if an upstream is already set, then <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> will just unset it. Press <kbd>u</kbd> again to set a new value.

Starting with `v2.4` and if the upstream is unset, you can also set upstream while pushing by using <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>`[REMOTE/]BRANCH`<kbd>RET</kbd>. You'll automatically be asked what branch to use as the upstream. Once an upstream has been set <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> will push to that without letting you change the upstream. So to *change* the upstream, you have to use the approach described in the previous paragraph.

Before `v2.4` it was also possible to set the remote branch that you are pushing to as the upstream branch using <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>`REMOTE/BRANCH`<kbd>RET</kbd>. But now the `--set-upstream` switch is no longer available in the push popup *by default*. You can get it back by setting `magit-push-current-set-remote-if-missing` to nil. That has two effects: the `--set-upstream` switch will be available again after the next restart and the approach described in the previous paragraph will no longer work.

---

If you want both features described in the second and third paragraph to be available at the same time, then leave `magit-push-current-set-remote-if-missing` untouched and add this to you init file:

```
(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-push-popup
  ?u "Set upstream" "--set-upstream")
```

Answer (score 11):

Press "`P C-u C-u P`" to make Magit ask you what remote and remote branch to use before pushing.

(With a single prefix argument ("`P C-u P`") Magit asks what remote to use.)

I found this by pressing `P C-h k P` in a Magit status buffer, reading the docs of `magit-push` and `magit-push-dwim` (these docs seem to be out of date, BTW), and experimenting.

PS: I use Magit `magit-1.2.0-2049-ge6839e8`.

Comment: This answer is a little bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's under the branch/configure section now:

`b` `C` `p` to set the pushRemote

Comment: Any idea how to specify a remote besides the default?

Answer (score 1):

As of Nov. 2016, and the latest `magit`, here's a partial solution:

`P` `e` - allows you to push `elsewhere`, but it's not remembered

I couldn't find a way for magit to `--set-upstream`, so I just did this from terminal, kind of a cheat but it got me over this problem:

`git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>`

And now the new upstream is saved, and I can build my next thing :)

Comment: "I can't find a way[...]to `--set-upstream`" - Perhaps you should try reading [tarsius' answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6023/5296)

Comment: sure, it's what helped me figure this out. Just, `magit` has changed a little since then, and my hope is that my solution saves someone an extra few minutes

Comment: The first paragraph of that answer explains how to change the upstream, and it works in the latest magit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `P C P` to set the `pushRemote` for every branch on a checked out repo using magit, using the Push -> Configure menu. It will probably automatically select origin for you.