# Magit equivalent of 'git remote add origin git@github.com:user/project.git'?

Tags: magit, remote

For those who are trying to determine how to do this here is the answer.
Yes the answer is in the docs!

I missed it on the first pass. Then looked at questions such as the below, trying <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> and thinking it could be set there but this was not the case.
[How do I set the upstream branch to push a local branch to in magit?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/how-do-i-set-the-upstream-branch-to-push-a-local-branch-to-in-magit/19150#19150)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent of the git command in Magit is to set a new Remote.

[This is where it is in the docs](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Remotes)

<kbd>M</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> creates a new remote.
When asked for the name of your remote, the usual answer is the name of your remote server, typically 'origin'

I hope this saves someone some time!