# Magit set upstream origin

Tags: magit

I'm having trouble understanding how Magit handles pushing local branches to remote

I create and checkout a new branch with `b c`.

I make some arbitrary change, and save returning to magit with `C-x g`

I stage and commit the change adding a commit message.

Now I want to push.

In a terminal I would use `git push --set-upstream origin <new_branch_name>`

In magit, I use `P` and either `u` or `p`.

Reading the docs and [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6021/change-a-branchs-upstream-with-magit) it sounds like `u` is the right choice.

when i hit `u` the status buffer reads

```
Set upstream of third_test_branch and push there (default origin/master):
```

looking for another input. When I enter `master` it then pushes to the master branch.

any other input at this point seems to return `match not found`

what am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use <kbd>p</kbd> to set the value of `branch.<name>.pushRemote` "the value has to be the name of an existing remote", and so you can only enter one of those.

It's quite common for there to only be `origin`, in which case that is the only valid value.  If you wish to add *new remotes*, use the Remotes popup bound to <kbd>M</kbd>.

Note that the remote branch for your `pushRemote` has the same name as the local branch, and so you are not prompted for that.  (i.e. <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> on a local branch `foo` with a pushRemote of `origin` pushes it to `origin/foo`).

If you use <kbd>u</kbd> to specify the 'upstream' then you are defining *both* a remote (`branch.<name>.remote`) and a branch (`branch.<name>.merge`); so there you could enter, say, `origin/bar` as an upstream for local branch `foo`.

---

The approach I tend to use is:

- Local `master` has upstream of `origin/master`.
- Local feature branch `foo` has pushRemote of `origin` and upstream of local `master` (an upstream of `origin/master` is more dangerous if you accidentally push to upstream<sup>1</sup>).
- My WIP on this feature is very regularly pushed to `origin/foo` (partly for backup purposes), using <kbd>P p</kbd>.
- At all times the status buffer shows me what I've added to `foo` since it was cut from `master` (being foo's upstream).  This is one of the nice benefits of having both an upstream and a pushRemote, and is the other reason why you might choose not to use `origin/master` as the feature branch upstream: You may not wish to be bothered by seeing newer upstream additions until it's time to merge, and `origin/master` would be updated if you do a general fetch from origin, whereas local `master` won't be updated unless you tell it to.
- Once the feature is ready to be merged into and pushed to `origin/master`...

  - Pull any upstream changes to `origin/master` into the local `master` branch.
  - If necessary, rebase the `foo` branch onto the updated `master`.
  - Merge `foo` into local `master`.
  - If happy, push the new `master` upstream to `origin/master`.

<sup>1</sup> I also use [this](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2589#issue-141444836) for added protection.

Comment: thanks, so for my local branch `foo` to push changes to a new remote branch i used `P u` and entered `origin/foo` and that worked with the new branch and the commit showing up on github.

Comment: Sure; but as above, if you just want to push `foo` to `origin/foo` (i.e. the branch name is the same) then you can use `P p` with `origin` as the `pushRemote` value.  I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.